# Creating Word documents from templates in Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have inherited an Access database from someone who built it about 20 years ago. Recently for some users out of the 90 who use it the function to create a Word document from templates that are populated by access has stopped working for some users. I have installed and reinstalled office so many times, I have made machines identical to each other and still one works and one doesn't. I'm hoping the below function will be enough for people who know a lot more about VBA than I to see something wrong.

I have done some research and thought at first it would be missing references but can be 100% sure that it is not. All users are running access runtime 2000 and a mixture of office 2010 and office 365 the users who work are both on office 365 and Office 2010.

Please see the below function and let me know if anything is glaringly obvious with the code, and let me know if more info is needed happy to supply it.

Edit* The issue I currently face is where the user clicks on the "Create document" button and then it seemingly does nothing. It doesn't error, it doesn't create the document and doesn't open word full screen like it should. It does however move onto the next part where it asks them if they would like to log this in the logs. What I have noticed is that it appears to try and open Word, which I have seen using "Procmon" but nothing opens in the foreground.

```
    Public Sub PRINT_DOC(TEMPLAT As String)

    Dim oword As Word.Application

'   Array bound increased from 20 to 100 [v1.1]
    Dim FIELDNAME(100) As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim FILE_STR As String
    Dim dbs As Database
    Dim COUNTER As Integer
    Dim COUNTA As Integer
    On Error GoTo notloaded

    Dim theError As Integer

    Err.NUMBER = 0
    Set oword = New Word.Application

notloaded:
    If Err.NUMBER = 429 Then
        Set oword = New Word.Application
        theError = Err.NUMBER
    End If

On Error GoTo Err_PRINT_DOC
    DoCmd.Hourglass True


    oword.Documents.Add TEMPLAT

    oword.Visible = True
    oword.Activate


    COUNTER = oword.ActiveDocument.FormFields.COUNT
    For COUNTA = 1 To COUNTER
        FIELDNAME(COUNTA) = oword.ActiveDocument.FormFields(COUNTA).Name
    Next

    For COUNTA = 1 To COUNTER
        Select Case FIELDNAME(COUNTA)
            Case "CONTACT": oword.ActiveDocument.FormFields(COUNTA).SELECT
                            oword.Selection.InsertBefore Forms![frm_correspondence]![CONTACT]
            Case "ADDRESS": oword.ActiveDocument.FormFields(COUNTA).SELECT
                            oword.Selection.InsertBefore Forms![frm_correspondence]![FULL_ADDRESS]
            Case "REFERENCE": oword.ActiveDocument.FormFields(COUNTA).SELECT
                            oword.Selection.InsertBefore Forms![frm_correspondence]![REFERENCE]
            Case "FAX": oword.ActiveDocument.FormFields(COUNTA).SELECT
                            oword.Selection.InsertBefore Forms![frm_correspondence]![FAX_NO]
            Case "SUBJECT": oword.ActiveDocument.FormFields(COUNTA).SELECT
                            oword.Selection.InsertBefore Forms![frm_correspondence]![JOBTITLE] & " - " & Forms![frm_correspondence]![SUBJECT]
            Case "JOB": oword.ActiveDocument.FormFields(COUNTA).SELECT
                            oword.Selection.InsertBefore Forms![frm_correspondence]![JOBTITLE]
            Case "REPORT": oword.ActiveDocument.FormFields(COUNTA).SELECT
                            oword.Selection.InsertBefore Forms![frm_correspondence]![SUBJECT]
            Case "DATE": oword.ActiveDocument.FormFields(COUNTA).SELECT
                            oword.Selection.InsertBefore Forms![frm_correspondence]![DATE]
            Case "SIGNED": oword.ActiveDocument.FormFields(COUNTA).SELECT
                            oword.Selection.InsertBefore Forms![frm_correspondence]![SIGNED]
            Case "FROM": oword.ActiveDocument.FormFields(COUNTA).SELECT
                            oword.Selection.InsertBefore Forms![frm_correspondence]![FROM]
            Case "TO": oword.ActiveDocument.FormFields(COUNTA).SELECT
                            oword.Selection.InsertBefore Forms![frm_correspondence]![TO]
            Case "CC": oword.ActiveDocument.FormFields(COUNTA).SELECT
                            oword.Selection.InsertBefore Forms![frm_correspondence]![CC]
            Case "DEAR": oword.ActiveDocument.FormFields(COUNTA).SELECT
                            oword.Selection.InsertBefore Forms![frm_correspondence]![DEAR]

            Case "INVOICE_SUM": oword.ActiveDocument.FormFields(COUNTA).SELECT
                            oword.Selection.InsertBefore Forms![frm_correspondence]![INVOICE SUM]
            Case "INVOICE_VAT": oword.ActiveDocument.FormFields(COUNTA).SELECT
                            oword.Selection.InsertBefore Forms![frm_correspondence]![INVOICE VAT]
            Case "INVOICE_NOTES": oword.ActiveDocument.FormFields(COUNTA).SELECT
                            oword.Selection.InsertBefore Forms![frm_correspondence]![INVOICE NOTES]
             Case "INVOICE_NUMBER": oword.ActiveDocument.FormFields(COUNTA).SELECT
                            oword.Selection.InsertBefore Forms![frm_correspondence]![INVOICE NO]
            Case "INVOICE_TOTAL": oword.ActiveDocument.FormFields(COUNTA).SELECT
                            oword.Selection.InsertBefore Forms![frm_correspondence]![INVOICE TOTAL]
        End Select
    Next

    oword.Visible = True
    oword.Activate

    If Forms![frm_correspondence]![COR PATH] <> "" And Not IsNull(Forms![frm_correspondence]![COR PATH]) Then
        FILE_STR = Forms![frm_correspondence]![COR PATH] & "\" & Forms![frm_correspondence]![FILE REF]
        oword.ActiveDocument.SaveAs FILENAME:=FILE_STR
    End If
    DoCmd.Hourglass False
    Set oword = Nothing

Exit_PRINT_DOC:
    Exit Sub

Err_PRINT_DOC:
    MsgBox Error$, vbExclamation, APP_NAME
    Resume Exit_PRINT_DOC
End Sub
```

Comment: What does *has stopped working* mean **exactly** ? -- And Access 2000 runtime, seriously? That's kinda obsolete.

Comment: Have added an edit to the original post explaining what isn't working. And yes I know access 2000 is very very obsolete.

Comment: Ok. You'll have to set a breakpoint and step through the code, to see where exactly it fails. Then we may be able to help. See [How to debug VBA code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try using late binding  like this

```
Dim oword As  Object: set oword = CreateObject("Word.Application")
```

insted of

```
Dim oword As Word.Application
```